# How is reviewing supposed to be done?

Tags: discussion

I have just recently noticed `review` section by my username.  "Ah, community chores", I thought. So I rolled my sleeves up and clicked the link, and indeed—the box on the right confirmed and explained what & why should I do there.

But for some reason I still cannot figure out *how* to do it—I mean *how to use the UI* to get things done.

For example: I reviewed couple of posts, but the list of posts never changes. It looks like a queue to me, but shouldn't the posts I've already reviewed disappear?

And how do I actually say that I've reviewed it? Not every posts actually need any action, so how do I say "this is OK"?

Am I just missing a button? (By the way, I'm using Opera.)

Comment: [How to review? Can we agree on a review 'policy'?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74194)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But for some reason I still cannot figure out how to do it—I mean how to use the UI to get things done.

You have 4 different tabs, attack them as required.

> e: I reviewed couple of posts, but the list of posts never changes. It looks like a queue to me, but shouldn't the posts I've already reviewed disappear?

Yes, but *first* there should be a progress report for you

[image]

Once you've completed this to 100%, the system will keep track of your progress and the review becomes a queue, rather than a read-only list.

[image: post reviewer badge completion]

> And how do I actually say that I've reviewed it? Not every posts actually need any action, so how do I say "this is OK"?

Clicking on the "review question"/"review answer" is the equivalent of saying "OK".

Comment: However, the badges [do not look like keys](http://i.imgur.com/XXGLD.png) in my browser. They simply look like badges to me, and clicking them only takes me to "Users earned this badge" site. The report is quite confusing: it seems like it's introducing some hybrid between badge and privilege.

Comment: @AloisMahdal yes, the pic like keys because it's from [dba.se] :P